# How to fill up excel names based on filename

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask if there is an excel macro or vba to automatically get the file name e.g. D01Q12013 and then add three new columns(District, Quarter, Year) to a table with existing data in the first thirteen columns, and populate the three new columns based on the filename (District - 01, Quarter - 1, Year - 2013)?

Comment: The answer to your question is a big yes. DIR function together with other string manipulation functions (Mid, len, left, right, etc.) can be used to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should get you started:

```
Sub GetName()

Range("A1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Name
Range("A2").Value = "District - " & Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 2, 2)
Range("A3").Value = "Quarter - " & Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 5, 1)
Range("A4").Value = "Year - " & Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 6, 4)

End Sub
```

The two key elements here:

1. ThisWorkbook.Name = Gives the name of the workbook in which the code is located. You could also use "ActiveWorkbook.Name" to get the name of the workbook that is active.
2. Mid = Allows you to extract a section of a piece of text (such as the filename of the workbook). The format for using this function is:

   MID(text_to_extract_from, start_position, number_of_characters)

So the line "Range("A4").Value = "Year - " & Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 6, 4)" sets the value of cell A4 to a phrase that begins with "Year - " and then uses the four characters beginning with the sixth character of the filename of the workbook where the code is located.

Using these elements and the macro recorder, you should be able to accomplish your goal of inserting new columns that contain portions of the filename.

Comment: Got it, it worked. Now on to the rest of the solution. Thanks!:)